# Opening of links in new tab on Safari iPhone

Tags: html, ios, iphone

I have a site that helps people create captions for their Instagram posts and evaluate hashtags. One of the features is as simple as making links of the hashtags to Instagram in order to see what types of images they contain. As I don't want the input they have just entered and evaluated to disappear I have made the links open in new tabs by using target="_blank" - this works perfectly on desktops but on iPhones nothing happens when you try to click on the hashtag links. I suspect that it might be some sort of protection by disabling target="_blank" links, but I am not sure. Everything is just simple html links. I have tried adding rel="noreferrer" but that didn't make any difference.

So if you have an explanation as to why it does not work that would helpful, but even more helpful would be a solution as to how I can obtain what I want on mobile devices as well, which is simply put: open a link in a new tab so that I don't lose input/state of page that I have just presented to the user.

Alternative solutions to the above issue are also very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this js code:

```
function openTab(url) {
    // Create link in memory
    var a = window.document.createElement("a");
    a.target = '_blank';
    a.href = url;

    // Dispatch fake click
    var e = window.document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    e.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    a.dispatchEvent(e);
};

openTab('http://www.google.com');
```

you can find the original post here: http://whoknew.dk/programmatically-opening-a-new-tab-window-on-mobile-safari-55.htm

Comment: Interesting I will give it a try. But strangely that links says that you can just use target _blank which doesn't work for me. It is however an old article so this may have changed.

Answer (score 0):

as `dispatchEvent` is deprecated, you could use:

```
function openTab(url) {
  // Create link in memory
  var a = window.document.createElement("a");
  a.target = '_blank';
  a.href = url;

  //click
  a.click();
};
```

Comment: Won't work with target `_blank` if there is no user interaction to open the new tab and the user has pop-ups blocked on their iOS device.