# HTML Anchor tag not opening a page on iPhone while working as expected everywhere else

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, hyperlink, anchor

I have a page that is basically a custom built video player that has a `<a href..></a>` tag one of the elements in the control bar which should open up a new page but for whatever reason it does not work on iPhone browsers but seems to be working fine everywhere else (desktop & android).

The actual code is this:

```
<a id="lb-anchor-link" href="http://apple.com" target="_blank">
   <div class="lb-asset" id="corner-logo" style="background-image: url([IMG_URL]); width: 150px; height: 60px;">
   </div>
</a>
```

AFAIK, this code works as expected so I am assuming some other elements are having an impact on this.

Note that the elements are dynamically generated via JS.

Test page (the anchor area is over the "CALL TO ACTION" imagine) is
[here](https://preview-players.brightcove.net/v2/accounts/3558447484001/players/ryEuKb9wG/preview/embeds/default/master/index.html?&playsinline=true&lbplayerURL=https://cdn2.logobar.tv/player/player.min.js?action=savePlayer&player_id=1333&client=&logoBgShape=rectangle&videoPlayer=Brightcove&player_name=scrubber%20test%20-%20brightcove&playLogo=false&playLogoPos=right&playLogoSize=200x200&playLogoType=horizontal&scrubberSize=60x60&delayScrubTime=2&transitionTime=1&controlBarPosition=over&transitionStyle=slideDown&logoMode=slideDown&progressFixed=false&progressFadeAfterTime=4&progressFadeTime=1&anchorURL=http://apple.com&anchorTarget=_blank&controlBarColor=102,102,102,0.7&controlBarBg=0&playColor=255,255,255,1&progressBarColor=255,255,255,1&iconColor=255,255,255,1&logoBgColor=0,0,0,0&progressBarHeight=60&skinColor=0,0,0,1&keepAssetsVisibleonPause=true&emails=Support@logobar.tv&logoLink=https://tracking.logobar.tv/uploads/21/1515695382.png&logoFName=.BRANDLOGO_1.png&logoFId=2979&anchorLink=https://tracking.logobar.tv/uploads/21/1515695426.png&anchorFName=.CTAExample_1.png&anchorFId=2980&scrubberLink=https://tracking.logobar.tv/uploads/21/1515695382.png&scrubberFName=.BRANDLOGO_1.png&scrubberFId=2979).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because of the IOS platforms default setting regarding opening new windows on a mobile browser. You will most likely need to write javascript to achieve what you're looking for

Here are some references: [Opening of links in new tab on Safari iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878745/opening-of-links-in-new-tab-on-safari-iphone)

Why `target="_blank` isnt working: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27725291/Html-problem-with-target-blank-on-iPad-does-not-open-a-new-window-on-the-iPad.html

Comment: Tested the same code without the target attribute and got the same result so I doubt that is it.